# Find string in specific context using grep

Tags: python, regex, grep

I want to find and extract all words that are surrounded by a specific context from a big file. All the lines in the file look something like like this, but with different words between `>`and `<\w>`:

```
<="UO" lemma="|" lex="|" sense="|" prefix="|" suffix="|" compwf="|" complemgram="|" ref="05" dephead="04" deprel="ET">and<\w>
```

I only want the output to be 'and'. So I basically want to extract all strings (words, punctuations and numbers) that are in the context `>xxx<\w>`. I tried a bunch of different alternatives with grep and regex, but I either get all the words or the pattern with `>` and `<\w>`... From the whole file I would want the output to look like this:

```
and 
we
appreciate
this
very 
much
.
```

And so on...

Comment: add the input text and expected output

Comment: sorry, for some reason it didn't show the first time I posted

Comment: "I only want the output to be 'and'" is not a sufficient explanation of what you are trying to achieve.  Please give us an example of what the output should look like; otherwise, my recommendation is to use this code: `echo "and"`

Comment: there must be words `we
appreciate
this
very 
much` within input text, I suppose. Update your input

Comment: so, you want all the words, punctuations, and numbers, in your file split on separate lines?  Thats all?

Comment: Okay I updated the question, it was wrongly put...

Comment: @sadmicrowave yes, but only the ones that are in the specific context >xxx<\w>.

Comment: @S.H the solution I provided is it ok? or did I misunderstood your problem?

Comment: @S.H check the update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pattern like this. This will match anything between `>` and `<\w>`.

```
import re
pat = re.compile(r'>(.*?)<\\w>')
pat.findall(input_string)
```

Comment: your pattern does not exclude the `>` and `<\w>` character sets from the desired results

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  Given the input file with the following values (I'm hoping I understand your use case):

```
<="UO" lemma="|" lex="|" sense="|" prefix="|" suffix="|" compwf="|" complemgram="|" ref="05" dephead="04" deprel="ET">and<\w>
<="UO" lemma="|" lex="|" sense="|" prefix="|" suffix="|" compwf="|" complemgram="|" ref="05" dephead="04" deprel="ET">we<\w>
<="UO" lemma="|" lex="|" sense="|" prefix="|" suffix="|" compwf="|" complemgram="|" ref="05" dephead="04" deprel="ET">appreciate<\w>
<="UO" lemma="|" lex="|" sense="|" prefix="|" suffix="|" compwf="|" complemgram="|" ref="05" dephead="04" deprel="ET">this<\w>
<="UO" lemma="|" lex="|" sense="|" prefix="|" suffix="|" compwf="|" complemgram="|" ref="05" dephead="04" deprel="ET">very<\w>
<="UO" lemma="|" lex="|" sense="|" prefix="|" suffix="|" compwf="|" complemgram="|" ref="05" dephead="04" deprel="ET">much<\w>
<="UO" lemma="|" lex="|" sense="|" prefix="|" suffix="|" compwf="|" complemgram="|" ref="05" dephead="04" deprel="ET">.<\w>
```

The following python regex should work for you:

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = re.compile(r'(?<=">)(.*)(?=<\\w>)')
>>> pat.findall(input_string)
['and', 'we', 'appreciate', 'this', 'very', 'much', '.']
```

Comment: your pattern will fail for punctuation marks. like the `.` at the end

Comment: what if there is `>` in between? like `>><\w>`

Comment: Have you tested it in an editor? That would make no difference. The .* captures any type of character and the (?=<\\w>) explicitly looks for the <\w> to close the match context. The only thing that would make it potentially break is if the context string inside the match area was actually the string <\w> and for some reason the match looked like: `><\w><\w>`

Comment: @salmanwahed, ok, if you see that as a problem, then it can be avoided by adding " to the first `match but don't include` brace like so `(?<=">)`, updated my answer